# Gocd task fails after shell script execution

Tags: shell, continuous-deployment, go-cd

Running GOCD server on windows server and agent on windows 10. One of the tasks in a pipeline is running shell script in agent using custom command in GOCD task.

As of now, shell script just has 1 line

```
echo "hello"
```

The script is executed fine when task is triggered, but the task fails in the pipeline console.

Update :
My config file for pipeline which triggers sh file. Content is same as above a single line echo command.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cruise xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="cruise-config.xsd" schemaVersion="106">
  <server artifactsdir="artifacts" agentAutoRegisterKey="270fb4b6-d548-435b-a4b5-a6f6952e1a4d" webhookSecret="eba9b673-0757-4577-807d-82dca985d17f" commandRepositoryLocation="default" serverId="359f16bd-f9c9-4c52-bd78-081df4069961" tokenGenerationKey="82d73c79-47f7-494e-9ec7-76639d4ec961" />
  <pipelines group="defaultGroup">
    <pipeline name="test1">
      <materials>
        <git url="http://infygit.ad.infosys.com/Mohit_Vora/InfyBankH2Dev.git" dest="codedev" />
      </materials>
      <stage name="defaultStage">
        <jobs>
          <job name="defaultJob">
            <tasks>
              <exec command="mvn clean install" workingdir="codedev">
                <runif status="passed" />
              </exec>
            </tasks>
            <artifacts>
              <artifact type="build" src="codedev/target/*.war" dest="deployWar" />
              <artifact type="build" src="codedev/tomcat.sh" dest="deployWar" />
              <artifact type="build" src="codedev/tomcat.bat" dest="deployWar" />
            </artifacts>
          </job>
        </jobs>
      </stage>
    </pipeline>
    <pipeline name="test2">
      <materials>
        <pipeline pipelineName="test1" stageName="defaultStage" />
      </materials>
      <stage name="defaultStage">
        <jobs>
          <job name="defaultJob">
            <tasks>
              <fetchartifact srcdir="deployWar" dest="warTestDeploy" pipeline="test1" stage="defaultStage" job="defaultJob">
                <runif status="passed" />
              </fetchartifact>
              <exec command="tomcat.sh" workingdir="warTestDeploy/deployWar">
                <runif status="passed" />
              </exec>
            </tasks>
          </job>
        </jobs>
      </stage>
    </pipeline>
  </pipelines>
  <agents>
    <agent hostname="MYSGEC241372D" ipaddress="10.123.75.196" uuid="37628ff5-91f7-4c9a-a5f5-615e937f2650" />
  </agents>
</cruise>
```

My console log:

```
##|19:47:17.280 [go] Start to build test2/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on MYSGEC241372D [C:\Program Files\Go Agent]
!!|19:47:17.280 [go] Task: fetch artifact [deployWar] => [warTestDeploy] from [test1/defaultStage/defaultJob]
&1|19:47:17.280 [go] Fetching artifact [deployWar] from [test1/13/defaultStage/1/defaultJob]
&1|19:47:26.211 [go] Saved artifact to [pipelines\test2\warTestDeploy] after verifying the integrity of its contents.
?0|19:47:26.211 [go] Task status: passed (8931 ms)
!!|19:47:26.211 [go] Task: tomcat.sh
?1|19:49:06.044 [go] Task status: failed (99833 ms) (exit code: -1073741819)
j1|19:49:06.122 [go] Current job status: failed
##|19:49:06.169 [go] Start to create properties test2/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on MYSGEC241372D [C:\Program Files\Go Agent]
ar|19:49:06.169 [go] Start to upload test2/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on MYSGEC241372D [C:\Program Files\Go Agent]
ex|19:49:06.274 [go] Job completed test2/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on MYSGEC241372D [C:\Program Files\Go Agent]
```

Comment: if you are asking about shell script code, there is a file named test.sh with content as echo "hello". if not then what other code are you asking for? I am calling this script from custom command by just writing test.sh in command text box without any arguments. as in if we were in cmd, to call the script all we would do is script name and then press enter so that sh script will run and control comes back to cmd.

Comment: right, my bad. You might want to add the info given in the comment to the question since readers expect everything to be nicely summarised there instead having to go through comments. I'm not a Windows users, but they have some sort of permissions, as well, so they. Maybe the script file lack execution permissions.

Comment: Please paste your config XML for this task, and the output that the task produces. A potential source of errors after a task succeeds is that you may have configured it to obtain some artifacts, but GoCD can't find the files. But with the lack of details in the question, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: thanks a ton Karl for correcting formatting in my question...I am a nube for SO. @moritz I don't have config file, everything did was from GUI, but I guess what you're asking would be in server folder in conf folder somewhere. I'll find it and paste it here along with screenshot of console. thanks for guidance.

Comment: @gogamote you can go to Admin -> Config XML where it shows you the whole config (though you might need to be admin to get there).

Comment: i have pasted config.xml. I am still stuck at same point, however i found that doing same thing in a batch file doesn't fail task, so i am continuing my work with batch. If someone thinks this is a bug, i would love to fork go-cd source and create a PR.

Comment: If you open a console on your gocd agent, with the user the agent process is running as (not sure on Windows but on Linux it's the "go" user).
You can try to execute the same shell script and see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. someone can affirm or counter me factually.

1. came across this somewhere in threads, gocd considers return codes when executing external shell or bat files. if return code is 0, it considers successful execution, if not, it considers it as a failed attempt at executing respective bat or shell script. which in my case, must be non-zero return code as different scripts and libraries consider different return code as success or fail. setting return code manually would be possible solution.
2. echo "hello" was just a experiment, when I added meaningful code, which was about making server instance up and running, it keeps new CMD window open until I kill server instance manually, which means, control never returns to gocd, and hence it suffers timeout error.

Open to comments on this, don't have access to code anymore.